# How can I program to check whether a number is a zeisel number or not?

Tags: java, functional-programming, number-theory

To know more about [zeisel numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeisel_number)

**A Zeisel number** is a **square-free** integer k with **at least three** prime factors which fall into the pattern

```
p[x] = a*p[x-1] + b
```

where a and b are some **integer** constants and x is the index number of each prime factor in the factorization, sorted from lowest to highest. For the purpose of determining Zeisel numbers, p[0] = 1.

I have written this code below in java. This function does test for positive b but not for **negative b**. How can I do that?

```
// function to caluculate zeisel number
public static boolean zeisel(int num) {
    // returning false if not squarefree
    if (Math.sqrt(num) == (int) Math.sqrt(num))
        return false;
    int fac = 2, count = 0, str = num;
    // arrray to store prime factors
    int[] fact;
    int a = 1, b = 0, i = 0;
    // counting number of factors
    while (num != 1) {
        if(num % fac == 0) {
            count++;
            num /= fac;
        }
        else 
            fac++;
    }
    num = str;
    fac = 2;
    // storing factors in array
    fact = new int[count]; 
    while (num != 1) {
        if(num % fac == 0) { 
            fact[i] = fac;
            i++;
            num /= fac;
        } else
            fac++;
    }
    if(i < 3)
        return false;
    // checking for zeisel equation
    while(a < fact[0]) {
        b = fact[0] - a;
        for(i = 1; i < count; i++) {
            if(fact[i] != a*fact[i -1] + b) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if(i == count) {
            return true;
        }
        a++;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Convert negative to positive.

Comment: `a` can't be negative, right ? wikipedia doesn't say anything about this, if `a` can be negative there can be infinite solutions for a and b !!!

Comment: `Math.sqrt(num) == (int) Mat.sqrt(num)` is not a proper test for "square-free".  "10" is a square-free number, but "18" is not because it can be evenly divided by a square (3^2).

Comment: a=8, b=-3 generates the factors 5, 37, 293, which produces the zeisel number 54205.   Ergo, negative b values are allowed.  So stopping the loop with `a < fact[0]` is not allowed.

Comment: There's code and some more discussion at https://oeis.org/A051015 from the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, which you should reference to double check your work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for any looping to determine the `a` and `b` factors.  You have two equations in two unknowns:

```
p1 = a * (1) + b
p2 = a * p1  + b
```

Subtracting the first from the second gives:

```
p2 - p1 = a * (p1 - 1)
```

Which you can use to directly solve for `a = (p2 - p1) / (p1 - 1)`, and assuming it is an integer, then solve for `b = p1 - a`.

So, after you've generated your factors in `fact[]` (with the corrected [square-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer) condition), your test could be something like:

```
if ((fact[1] - fact[0]) % (fact[0] - 1) != 0)
    return false;

int a = (fact[1] - fact[0]) / (fact[0] - 1);
int b = fact[0] - a;

for(int i=2; i<count; i++) {
    if (fact[i] != a*fact[i-1] + b) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```